# Make load more function using Next JS and Typescript

Tags: typescript, next.js

I have this code to call data from API

```
export async function getTags(props?: { page?: number }): Promise<GhostTags> {
  const tags = await api.tags.browse(....)
  return tags
}
```

I'm using `getStaticProps` to fetch data and render them

```
export const getStaticProps: GetStaticProps = async () => {

    const posts = await getTags()
    // Some code

    return {
        props: {
            posts,
        },
    }
}

interface CmsData{
  // Some code
}
interface IndexProps {
  myData : CmsData
}

const TagIndex = ({ myData }: IndexProps) => {
    return (
        // some code
    )
}
```

Everythings are working fine. But now, I want to make a `Load more` button. It's mean when I click `Load more`, data will be fetch.

I tried make a function inside `const TagIndex = () => {}`

```
 const loadMore = async(page)=> {
     let res = await getTags(page)
     // some code
 }
```

but I got `Module not found: Can't resolve 'fs'`

Why ? and How can I fix them ?

Comment: Looks like you are using Node.js `fs` module somwhere, maybe inside `createNextFeatureImages`?

Comment: @Camilo I tried remove `createNextFeatureImages` but it not work.  I had edited my question

Comment: Check inside `api.tags.browse()` then. You can't use `fs` outside of Node.

Comment: Please provide a [mre].